Getting 400 response code while trying to fetch token from our application using karate framework
String Token = given().contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
                    .formParam("grant_type", "password")
                    .formParam("username", "admin")
                    .formParam("password", "admin")
                    .formParam("client_id", "yyyy")
                    .when().post("/realms/XXXXX/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                    .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().path("access_token"); System.out.println(Token);

Above code will login our application and return token value after successful login. Newly generated token will be used of other API's. This code works fine. I tried same thing using karate framework but it shows 400 response code.
I created below feature file. While executing it returns response 400 Feature:Authentication
Background: Initialize stuff Given url 'https://test.com'

@ignore
Scenario: test register api print 'hello'

@login
Scenario: verify protected endpoint /posts 
  Given path 'realms/XXXXX/protocol/openid-connect/token'
  And header Content-type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
  And form field grant_type = 'authorization_code'
  And form field username = 'admin'
  And form field password = 'Password'
  And form field client_id = 'YYYY'
  When method post
  Then status 200
  And print response


sorry, no idea. hopefully someone else here can help. try taking the help of the server-side team to troubleshoot. many teams use karate for form field submissions without issues
